# How do I check each number instead just the one value?

Tags: python, modulus

Divisors:
For numbers from 2 to 100, print a series of lines indicating which numbers are divisors of other numbers.  For each, print out “X divides Y”, where X <= Y, and both X and Y are between 2 and 100.  The first few lines will be:
2 divides 2
3 divides 3
2 divides 4
4 divides 4
5 divides 5
etc.

So far I have this

```
x = 2
y = 2
while y <= 100:
      while y <= 100:
            if y % x == 0:
                print(x, 'divides', y)
                y += 1
            elif y % x != 0:
                y += 1
```

Im not sure how to make it test the other values of x and y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a corrected version of your code for a smaller value of `y` up to 6.
You can extend it to 100.

*Explanation*: The first while loop checks for `y` value. For each `y` value, you check for its divisors using the second while loop which runs over `x`. You update `x` by 1 within the inner `while` loop and update `y` by 1 within the outer `while` loop. Comment below if something is unclear.

*Problems with your code*: You were using two `while` loops just for `y`, one of which was redundant. Moreover, you were not incrementing `x` as you clearly pointed out in your question. Your `elif` was also not required because you were incrementing `y` in both the cases.

```
y = 2
while y <= 6: # Replace 6 by 100 here
    x = 2 # Reset x to 2 for every y value because you count divisors from 2
    while x <= y:
        if y % x == 0:
            print(x, 'divides', y)
        x += 1  
    y += 1
```

**Output**

```
2 divides 2
3 divides 3
2 divides 4
4 divides 4
5 divides 5
2 divides 6
3 divides 6
6 divides 6
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do a work. Give it a try, if something is unclear give me a shout

```
x = int(input("Give the range you want to check numbers in: "))

for number in range(1,x):
    for value in range(1,number+1):
        if number % value == 0:
            print(number, " is divided by", value)
```

Output for input "10":

```
1  is divided by 1
2  is divided by 1
2  is divided by 2
3  is divided by 1
3  is divided by 3
4  is divided by 1
4  is divided by 2
4  is divided by 4
5  is divided by 1
5  is divided by 5
6  is divided by 1
6  is divided by 2
6  is divided by 3
6  is divided by 6
7  is divided by 1
7  is divided by 7
8  is divided by 1
8  is divided by 2
8  is divided by 4
8  is divided by 8
9  is divided by 1
9  is divided by 3
9  is divided by 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *enumerate* here and cycling through the indexes prior to every item will produce the results you are trying to get

```
x = [*range(2, 101)]
for idx, item in enumerate(x):
    for i in x[:idx +1]:
        if not item % i:
            print('{} divides {}'.format(i, item))
```

> ```
> 2 divides 2
> 3 divides 3
> 2 divides 4
> 4 divides 4
> 5 divides 5
> 2 divides 6
> 3 divides 6
> 6 divides 6
> ...
> 99 divides 99
> 2 divides 100
> 4 divides 100
> 5 divides 100
> 10 divides 100
> 20 divides 100
> 25 divides 100
> 50 divides 100
> 100 divides 100
> ```